# upload file into Heroku using FileZilla

Tags: heroku, filezilla

How can I upload a file from local to a Heroku app public folder using FileZilla?

I'm able to upload into EC2 but not into Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

In general, uploading files to Heroku doesn't make much sense thanks to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

If you're trying to update code or something that's "part of" your application you should instead commit it to your Git repository and push the new commits to Heroku. This will trigger another build.

If you're trying to add content it might make more sense to [store it in an off-site file or object store like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).